# Replace special characters with gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Is there a way to replace special character strings in R with gsub?
I have a few columns which have the `\\n` in them and I wish to change it to `\n` but the gsub doesn't work

Here is an example:

```
gsub("\\n", "\n", "\\n this is a test \\n data")
```

I receive the following output:

```
[1] "\\n this is a test \\n data"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want by adding the argument fixed=T at the end of your gsub commmand.

```
gsub("\\n", "\n", "\\n this is a test \\n data",fixed=T)
[1] "\n this is a test \n data"
```